# Error running trueaccord.scalapb TypeError from Python script

Tags: python, maven, plugins, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run the example in https://github.com/aegnor/scalapb-maven-example
The pom.xml does not run for me unless I make some changes:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.trueaccord.scalapb</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalapbc_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Generating Scala code on Windows requires Python 2.x to be installed on your system. -->
                    <id>generate-scala-protobuf-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.trueaccord.scalapb.ScalaPBC</mainClass>
                <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                <executableDependency>
                    <groupId>com.trueaccord.scalapb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scalapbc_2.11</artifactId>
                </executableDependency>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--proto_path=${project.basedir}/src/main/proto</argument>
                    <argument>--scala_out=${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/proto</argument>
                    <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/*.proto</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What I did was to add the com.trueaccord.scalapb dependency and set to true includeProjectDependencies after this it actually runs. However now I am getting an error that says:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoseO\AppData\Local\Temp\protocbridge1191463098726442484.py", line 6, 
  in <module>
  s.sendall(content)
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
  --scala_out: protoc-gen-scala: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Now I capture the generated code from the plugin. There are two files that get generated to execute the command:

```
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3115202540073112270\bin\protoc.exe, --plugin=protoc-gen-scala=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\protocbridge875241605176874095.bat, --proto_path=C:\dev\examples\scalapb-maven-example/src/main/proto, --scala_out=C:\dev\examples\scalapb-maven-example\target/generated-sources/proto, C:\dev\examples\scalapb-maven-example/src/main/proto/*.proto]
```

The first file is a batch file:

```
@echo off
python.exe -u C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\protocbridge8364859980217271731.py 60354
```

The second is a phyton file and this is where the error occurs.

```
    import sys, socket
content = sys.stdin.read()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', int(sys.argv[1])))
s.sendall(content)
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == '':
        break
    sys.stdout.write(data)
s.close()
```

can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It's probably a Python versioning issue.  In Python 2.x strings were, by default, bytes-like (8-bit characters).  In Python 3.x strings are, by default, unicode (more than 8 bits per character).  The read() function in line 2 returns a string, but socket.sendall requires 8-bit data - or at least I think so.  I'm pretty sure this code will run in Python 2.x but not 3.x.  What version of Python is installed on your computer?

Comment: From my cygwin bash I get:                $ python --version
Python 2.7.13

Comment: From windows command I get   C:\dev>python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: From windows command I get the same
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\protocbridge6544527124403273675.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.sendall(content)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
--scala_out: protoc-gen-scala: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Thanks for your tip I uninstall all versions of Python and now it compiles!

Comment: Good.  You might want to tell github.com/aegnor that he needs to fix his example, or at least document this issue.

Comment: I have already done that by creating a link to this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the plugin com.trueaccord.scalapb:scalapbc_2.11:0.6.6 uses Python version 2 and I had installed Python version 3. Once I reinstall the right version it all worked.